# What are SN1ʹ and SN2ʹ reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, notation

I went through the problems 119 and 120 from chapter 4 *Reaction mechanism* of Singh's *Conceptual problems in organic chemistry* [1, p. 190] targeting nucleophilic substitution reactions for 3-bromo-3-methylcyclohex-1-ene:

> [image: 119: 3-bromo-3-methylcyclohex-1-ene + MeOH; 120: 3-bromo-3-methylcyclohex-1-ene + MeO^−]

The answer of the problem **119** is $\mathrm{S_N1'}$, and that of **120** is $\mathrm{S_N2'}$. I actually can't figure out what $\mathrm{S_N1'}$ ($\mathrm{S_N1}$ prime) and $\mathrm{S_N2'}$ ($\mathrm{S_N2}$ prime) are.

Also, how does the answer change by changing the nucleophile?

#### Reference

1. Singh, D. K. *Conceptual Problems in Organic Chemistry: For Engineering and Medical Entrance Examinations*, 3rd ed.; Pearson India, **2013**. ISBN 978-93-325-8207-1.

Comment: The ' indicates that the actual substitution site is not where the leaving group is attached. In the cases presented, the nucleophile would add at the upper end of the double bond.

Answer (score 14):

The primed version of $\mathrm{S_N1}$ and $\mathrm{S_N2}$ can only occur if there is a double bond in the vicinity of the leaving group as in your example. I have drawn both possibilities for the $\mathrm{S_N2}$ case in the scheme below.

[image: SN2 and SN2' of methanolate with the starting material]
**Scheme 1:** Comparison of the reaction products in an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ (top) and $\mathrm{S_N2'}$ (bottom) pathway.

The $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction is as you expect it to be. The $\mathrm{S_N2'}$ reaction uses the double bond as an electron relay system. Instead of the nucleophile (here: $\ce{OMe-}$) directly interacting with the $\unicode{x3c3}^*(\ce{C-Br})$ orbital, the π system interacts with the σ* orbital. The nucleophile then interacts with the π system’s LUMO (corresponding to the middle orbital of the allyl π system) to perform the attack. Since the nucleophilic attack and the leaving group are on different carbon atoms, relayed by the π system, this is not a direct $\mathrm{S_N2}$ but a derivative of it ($\mathrm{S_N2'}$).

The same logic can be applied to $\mathrm{S_N1'}$: here, the intermediate carbocation is not a localised one but an allyl cation.

The primed versions here are observed because not only the bimolecular attack on the highly substituted tertiary carbon ($\mathrm{S_N2}$) is unlikely — this carbon is tertiary which usually already implies no $\mathrm{S_N2}$ — but also the capturing of the carbocation under $\mathrm{S_N1}$ conditions is more likely to happen at the sterically much less hindered carbon atom.

As to why methanol predominantly attacks according to an $\mathrm{S_N1}$-type mechanism while methanolate predominantly follows an $\mathrm{S_N2}$-type mechanism I will refer you back to your textbook; the reasons are stated pretty often.