# Difference between SN' and elimination reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

My professor has recently taught us about **SN'** reaction example in which **3-bromo-3-methyl-but-1-ene** was reacted with with **KCN** to yield **4-methyl-pent-3-ene-nitrile** as the major product.When I asked him why elimination didn't take place,my professor replied that it was based on experimental data.
Can anyone please clarify whether  the reaction is correct?If yes,then why elimination is not taking place.

Also,I was very surprised that I couldn't find any article on SN' reactions online..

Comment: Many factors contribute as to whether SN1, E1, SN2, E2 occur. By that way, it is not SN'. It is SN1

Comment: @M.L No, I am talking about SN '( prime) reactions, not $SN _1$.

Comment: [What are SN1' and SN2' reactions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82880/)

Comment: @andselisk  Thank you for the related link. Can you please explain why in my case and also in the related answer why E2 elimination is not taking place to form the major product?

Comment: Honestly, I have not heard of this type of reaction before. But why can't we logically say this is the major product because SN1 leads to allylic carbocation where you can actually insert the CN in the specified position leaving the double bond in a more stable position.